# Postgresql current_time stamp in Asia/kolkata changes when I change system date time

Tags: sql, postgresql, timezone

I have Postgresql installed on my system which is in India so timezone comes in `Asia/kolkata`.

What I need is current_timestamp so I tried as following queries:

```
select now()

select current_timestamp AT TIME ZONE 'Asia/Kolkata'
```

Which obviously gives me time-stamp correctly.

**But if I change my system date or time and then I use this query then it is giving me the result with changed date time. Which is obviously wrong.**

How Can I query or change neccessary conf to make such a way that the time stamp should be always comes correctly as **Asia/Kolkata and which should be in-depended of System date time.**

**Postgresql version : 9.3**

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that using PostgreSQL alone, `now()`and `current_timestamp` depend on the system date. Basically, everything running on your server is based on the system date.

You have to make sure your system date is accurate (with `ntp` sync) or use an external service.

Here is a way to do request external time using SQL only, but it's far from being effective or even extremely accurate:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION external_now() RETURNS TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE AS $$
    DECLARE last_external_now TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE := null;
    BEGIN
        CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE external_now (
            now text
        );

        COPY external_now
        FROM PROGRAM 'curl -s http://www.timeapi.org/utc/now -w "\n"';

        SELECT CAST(now AS TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE)
        FROM external_now
        ORDER BY now DESC
        LIMIT 1
        INTO last_external_now;

        DROP TABLE external_now;

        return last_external_now;
    END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql 
    VOLATILE 
    -- allow non superuser to call this function 
    SECURITY DEFINER
    COST 100000
;
```

You have to create this function as a superuser but you can run it as anyone:

```
test=> select external_now();
      external_now
------------------------
 2016-04-26 07:00:17+00
(1 row)

test=> select external_now() AT TIME ZONE 'Asia/Kolkata';
      timezone
---------------------
 2016-04-26 12:30:21
(1 row)
```

Comment: it is a good suggestion. In this I have to create table everytime and delete everytime . Is there any alternate way?

Comment: I don't know if you could in pure sql.

Comment: Getting the following error: ERROR:  `program "curl -s http://www.timeapi.org/utc/now -w "\n"" failed
DETAIL:  child process exited with exit code 1
CONTEXT:  SQL statement "COPY external_now
        FROM PROGRAM 'curl -s http://www.timeapi.org/utc/now -w "\n"'"
PL/pgSQL function external_now() line 8 at SQL statement
********** Error **********

ERROR: program "curl -s http://www.timeapi.org/utc/now -w "\n"" failed
SQL state: XX000`

Comment: You have to find a program that works for your operating system version, what's the result of ´curl -s http://www.timeapi.org/utc/now -w "\n"´

Comment: I am using `windows 10` OS

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110220/discussion-between-santhucool-and-clement-prevost).